# Cropping an Image Using 2D Arrays?

Tags: arrays, image, 2d, crop, pgm

I am completely lost on this assignment, any help would be appreciated guys! I am reading in a PGM image and making changes to it. I have already written some code to increase the brightness on it, but I don't know how to crop it.

My brighten code for an example:

```
public static short[][] brighten(short[][] orig, short amount) {

    short[][] returnArray = new short[orig.length][orig[0].length];
    for(int i = 0; i < orig.length; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < orig[0].length; ++j){
            returnArray[i][j] = (short)(orig[i][j]+amount);
        }

    }

    return returnArray;
}
```

So I have tried to use something like this but it doesn't seem to be working either:

```
public static short[][] crop(short[][] orig, int ULx, int ULy, int >LRx, int LRy) {

    short[][] returnArray = new short[orig.length][orig[0].length];
    for (int i = ULx; i <= LRx; i++) {
        for (int j = ULy; j <= LRy; j++){
            returnArray[i][j] = (short)(orig[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a nested `for` loop like in your brighten example, but only copy certain values across:

- to crop from the left side across, start the loop iterating across the rows at the value to crop from.
- to crop from the right side across, start the loop at 0 but limit it at the value to crop to.

Same concepts apply to the vertical cropping.

Here is my amended code - this time in Java for you :)

```
    short[][] returnArray = new short[orig.length][orig[0].length];

    int ReturnArrayX=0, ReturnArrayY;
    for (int i = ULx; i <= LRx; i++)
    {
        ReturnArrayY=0;
        for (int j = ULy; j <= LRy; j++)
        {
            returnArray[ReturnArrayX][ReturnArrayY] = (short)(orig[i][j]);
            ReturnArrayY++;
        }
        ReturnArrayX++;
    }
    return returnArray;
```

This probably isn't the most efficient way of doing it, but it gets it done and is clear to understand :)

Basically, you have two variables iterating through the Original array of "pixels", and another two variables iterating over the destinations for these variables - the original variables might start at 5 to crop from 5 pixels in, but with these new 2 variables, they'll be inserted starting at (0,0) in the resulting array. As soon as a pixel is added, the destination variables update.

**Important:** Once again, you'll probably have to tweak the order of the loops over the variables. I haven't tested this code, so I've got no idea how it'll work. The theory is there but the practical may not be. Just let it run and see if it's rotated the picture - if it has, you need to switch two variables around.

Hope this helps,

hnefatl

Comment: I'm trying to respond with some code, forgive me I am new to this forum. But my layout is all  bunched up. How do I set code off in a box like you did? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3426485 Put 4 spaces before the line of code :) When you're typing the edit, click "code" at the top and it'll tell you what to do. Or you can put a '`' character before and after something to "code" it inline.

Comment: 'code'public static short[][] crop(short[][] orig, int ULx, int ULy, int LRx, int LRy) {
  
  short[][] returnArray = new short[orig.length][orig[0].length];
  for (int i = ULx; i <= LRx; i++) {
   for (int j = ULy; j <= LRy; j++){
    returnArray[i][j] = (short)(orig[i][j]);
   }
  }
  return returnArray;
 }'code'
@hnefatl
I have attempted to translate it into Java but to no avail it doesn't work. ANy help? :)
Edit: I really cant get this code reply down >_<

Comment: Does it do anything at all? Have you tried stepping through the code in debugging and checking that it does what you think it does? It looks OK in java, can't see any glaring mistakes :/ RE the code sections, in the example the page gives you, the word "code" would be in the code block - just use the backwards apostrophe at the beginning and the end.

Comment: @user3426485 Oh, my mistake, I've just realised what's wrong. I'll amend my code in the answer.